# Very strange byte string. Cannot convert to str using Python

Tags: python, byte

This code worked perfectly some weeks ago. But something has changed.

I download data from site.

```
txt = urlopen(url, timeout=60).readlines()
for line in txt:
    print(line.strip().decode("utf-8"))
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position
>   0: invalid start byte

print (txt) gives me:

[b'\xc0\xe2\xf2\xee\xec\xe0\xf2\xe8\xf7\xe5\xf1\xea\xe0\xff \xe7\xe0\xe3\xf0\xf3\xe7\xea\xe0 \xed\xe5\xe4\xee\xf1\xf2\xf3\xef\xed\xe0']

I tried to recognize this byte string with online converters, but they couldn’t do it.

May be this is important. This code downloads stock market quotes from

https://www.finam.ru/profile/moex-akcii/nlmk-ao/export/?market=1

With its help I received such lines earlier

NLMK,D,20200103,000000,143.9800000,144.7400000,143.3000000,144.5000000,4578730
NLMK,D,20200106,000000,144.4800000,144.4800000,140.8800000,141.9400000,6600390
NLMK,D,20200108,000000,139.0000000,139.5000000,137.8000000,139.5000000,9260390
NLMK,D,20200109,000000,139.2000000,143.6000000,139.2000000,141.9600000,10108630
NLMK,D,20200110,000000,142.5400000,145.1200000,140.8000000,143.6200000,9444490
NLMK,D,20200113,000000,143.7000000,146.9800000,142.4800000,146.8400000,7138040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have looked at the page source, you would have noticed:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />`

This page simply isn't in UTF-8… and if you decode that bytestring using Windows-1251, you get a string: `Автоматическая загрузка недоступна`. From your first name I guess you should understand Russian…